# ScrollView Open my edittexts and work only if open

Tags: android, android-edittext, scrollview, android-linearlayout

i have a bad problem. i need to use a scrollview into my app, but this on start open editext Keyboard. 
If Keyboard is open, scrollview work, but if i close the keybord scroll not work.
How to resolve this ploblem?

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >


       <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/taglio"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_weight="1">

       <Button
        android:text="+"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/piutagliodonna"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:alpha="0.70"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editTexttagliodonna"
        android:hint="0"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:text="-"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/menotagliodonna"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:alpha="0.70"/>



       </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: ok now when activity start the keyboard is close but my scroll view dont work. i have added this code on first linearlayout :   `android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but change and add `RelativeLayout to LinearLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="pl.com.qubuss.test.RegisterActivity">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/nameET"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:hint="@string/nameTextHint"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:width="200dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/surnameET"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nameET"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nameET"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/nameET"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:hint="@string/surnameTextHint" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/emailET"
    android:hint="@string/emailTextHint"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/surnameET"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/surnameET"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/surnameET"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/username_registerET"
    android:layout_below="@+id/emailET"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/emailET"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/emailET"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:hint="@string/usernameTextHint" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/password_registerET"
    android:layout_below="@+id/username_registerET"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/username_registerET"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/username_registerET"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:hint="@string/passwordTextHint" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/registerButton"
    android:id="@+id/registerButton"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/conPasswor_registerET"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/conPasswor_registerET"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/password_registerET"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/password_registerET"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/password_registerET"
    android:hint="@string/conPasswordTextHint" />
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```